# Is there anyway to run a .bat command on chromebook?

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, chromebook

This is the command I want to run (excluding the real urls and names):

@echo off

start "name" "url"

start "name" " url"

start "name" "url"

start "name" "url"

start "name" "url"

start "name" "url"

Comment: Why not make a bunch of bookmarks in a folder in chrome and open them all at once?

Answer (score 3):

Batch files are not supported on Chromebook because they are specific to the Windows operating system. If you do not have Windows on your Chromebook (which you probably don't), this will not work.

You can create a script with similar functionality in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Similar to @echo off
exec 1>/dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null

# Similar to start
/path/to/browser 'url1'
/path/to/browser 'url2'
```

Comment: Does ChromeOS have the `xdg-open` command (which is the closest equivalent of the Windows `start` command)? If yes, it's better to use `xdg-open url`.

Comment: I don't think ChromeOS has xdg-utils built in. You could always install it, but for this I think it's a bit overkill. If your system does include xdg-open then it would be best to use that.

Comment: So if i find the browsers path it would go like this


#! /bin/bash

exec 1>/dev/null
exec2>/dev/null

/find/find/find 'url+1'
/find/find/find 'url+2'

and save it as.... ?

Comment: Use `!#/bin/bash`, without the space. Doesn't matter what you save the file as, although conventionally you would use the `.sh` suffix. Also remember to make the file executable with `chmod +x file.sh`